# Creating observation points(vertices) around a line feature in ArcGIS 10.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, line

Is there any way to create observation points(vertices) or lets just say points on a line feature. What I have is a line feature and I wanna put observation points around that feature, each one with a distance of 10 Meters to the other one. Does anybody know a way to do that? Maybe a tool or something.

Comment: @Alexandre Neto Ok thanks you are right, sorry I havent checked it before but I have a different problem now anyway. I tried to use "construct points" from the editor but when I have chosen my line feature and wanna click on "construct points" I get an error saying: "Point features could not be created. The map does not contain a point target. Add an editable point layer and/or a point template to the map".

Comment: Since your problem is substantially different now, you should probably ask a new one :) That will get more attention than a comment in your original Question.

Comment: Yeah you are probably right thx. May I ask if u might have an idea already? :D

Comment: It happens so often in ArcGIS that there is just tiny little change needed thats why Im asking